# Can I have more than 15 active connections in my IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: ide, visualstudiocode, illuminatedcloud, intellij

I noticed that every time when I have above 15 active connections to Salesforce orgs, I can't do the new connection (in my IntelliJ IDE). I use Illuminated Cloud 2 plugin to connect this

Is there a way to omit this?
I work on many orgs, and it sometimes require more than 15 active connections to different orgs

Do other IDEs (Visual Studio code or Webstorm) have the same problems or do they allow to have a bigger number of connections?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to have more than 15 active connections (I usually run at around 10-12 but certainly 15 is not the maximum I've had and I've currently got 16 on the go).

I add the connections by either creating scratch orgs or using `sfdx force:auth:web:login` to add OAuth 2-based access to other types of org.

The best place to ask about this is the dedicated Illuminated Cloud forums [over here](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/g/qanda).